# Tie a Blob to a Datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, image-uploading, blobstore

I have been banging my head against the wall on this one, for some reason I am having trouble tying the different aspects of Google App Engine together to make this work.

Basically I want to let a user upload a photo to the Blobstore, which I have working in the below code, and then I want to put the BlobKey into a list which will be stored in a database entity.  So here is my code to upload the image and where in here can I get the BlobKey so that I can store it?

```
class MainHandler(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")
        #there is a lot more code in here where I get all the following info but it isn't relevant
        location_db = Location(
                    description=description,
                    submitter=submitter,
                    user_id=user_id, 
                    title=title,
                    locationtype = locationtype)
            #This is what I would like to do but I don't know where to get thr BlobKey
            location_db.blobRefs.append(BlobKey)
            location_db.put()

        for b in blobstore.BlobInfo.all():
            self.response.out.write('<li><a href="/serve/%s' % str(b.key()) + '">' + str(b.filename) + '</a>')

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/main')

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, blob_key):
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        if not blobstore.get(blob_key):
            self.error(404)
        else:
            self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key), save_as=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
blob_info = upload_files[0]
self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

I think it's that

```
blob_info.key()
```

you are missing. Grab that, stuff it into your list. Docs also note:

> In this handler, you can store the blob key with the rest of your application's data model. The blob key itself remains accessible from the blob info entity in the datastore. 
>   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob